# jhtml::script no longer works in joomla 3.7

Tags: javascript, joomla

The following code used to work before I upgraded to 3.7 but the line "JHtml::script('com_members/site.js', array(), true);" no longer loads the site.js

```
class MembersViewMembersELso extends JViewLegacy
{
        // Overwriting JView display method
        function display($tpl = null) 
        {
                // Get data from the model
                $state = $this->get('State');
                $items = $this->get('Items');
                $pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
                // Check for errors.
                if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
                {
                        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                        return false;
                }
                // Assign data to the view
                $this->state = $state;
                $this->items = $items;
                $this->pagination = $pagination;  
                // get the stylesheet (with automatic lookup, possible template overrides, etc.)
                JHtml::stylesheet('com_members/site.stylesheet.css', array(), true);
                // insert js code for onsubmit
                JHtml::script('com_members/site.js', array(), true);
                // Display the view
                parent::display($tpl);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JHtml::Script` and `JHtml::Stylesheet` are not the ideal methods to use if you just want to include one JavaScript/CSS file. There is a lot of unnecessary overhead used in these methods and they both use the highly complex `includeRelativeFiles` method (you can find all 3 methods in the `libraries/cms/html/html.php` ).

A cleaner and simpler way to include files is to directly is to do the following (you will need, of course, to delete the `JHtml::Script` and `JHtml::Stylesheet` in your code above):

```
$objDocument = JFactory::getDocument();
$objDocument->addStyleSheet(JUri::base() .'com_members/site.stylesheet.css');
$objDocument->addScript(JUri::base() .'com_members/site.js');
```

Comment: Thankyou. I will use your suggestion, but do you have any idea why the JHtml::Script statement suddenly fails under Joomla 3.7?